# Upload File restriction for second time

Tags: php, magento

I am preparing a form in Magento where seller can upload their ID proofs, but I want to restrict them from uploading the file 2nd time. How can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "uploading the file 2nd time"?

Comment: once the file is uploaded and form is submitted then when  the user/seller open the page for edit they should not be able to upload the file again

Comment: Is this upload file value save in attribute or table at any place?